# copy one bitmap into another preserving transparency

Tags: android

I am trying to copy a png to another one

```
Bitmap overlay = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(mContext.getResources(), R.drawable.logo);
Buffer buf = new Buffer
overlay.copyPixelsToBuffer(buf);
myImage.copyPixelsFromBuffer(buf);
```

I am not sure what kind of buffer do I have to use there and also I dont know if this is the correct approach. Also, no offset parameter when copying into the new bitmap?

Thanks and sorry for my noobish questions :S

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one way using canvas

```
Bitmap overlay = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(mContext.getResources(), R.drawable.logo);
Bitmap background = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(mContext.getResources(), R.drawable.bgr).copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true); 

Canvas canvas = new Canvas(background);

canvas.drawBitmap(overlay, 10, 10, null);

return background;
```